# How to set up SSL with a TCP client in Akka 2.4.6?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to set up a TCP connection on TLS but can't find any recent documentation on that. I [found something about Akka streams 2.2](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/java/io-tcp.html) did manage to find something for 2.4.x.

I have been looking at [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/io-tcp.html) documentation

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the [`TLS`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/#akka.stream.scaladsl.TLS$) object in Akka Streams.

It would create a [`BidiFlow`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/#akka.stream.scaladsl.BidiFlow) you could use to convert plaintext to cypher text and vice versa.